# localhost doesn't display same errors as public domain

Tags: php, xampp, case-sensitive

I'm having an issue where everything works fine on my localhost but when I put the code on a public domain it trips over every small pebble that localhost didn't care about (and I obviously overlooked).

How can I make my localhost trip over the same pebbles so I fix the issues before publishing it?

I tried `error_reporting = E_ALL` but it didn't seem to work.

Best example I have is:

localhost is able to find `/language/EN/` while the folder is actually named `language/en/` but public domain gives an error. Is this a windows vs unix thing?

Comment: Windows is Case Insensitive and Unix/Linux is VERY Case Sensitive. So the answer to you question is YES

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux the path is case sensitive, under Windows it's not.

Probably the only comprehensive solution would be to use Linux on your development machine as well.